# How can I set up a ticket alert for Trenitalia trains that haven't been loaded yet?

Tags: trains, italy

Around the December timetable change, Trenitalia is notoriously late in loading night trains between Sicily and Northern Italy (as [The Man in Seat61 writes](https://www.seat61.com/train-travel-in-italy.htm): *The Milan-Sicily night train usually gets loaded last of all!* (this is about ICN 1964)).  At the same time, Christmas is a popular travel time.  At the time of writing (24 November), for 6/7 January, the few trains that have been loaded are partially already sold out.  Therefore, one can expect that once more trains get loaded, they sell out quickly, so travellers need to be alert and book as soon as possible.

Is there any service to put an alert when a particular train gets loaded?  I know Raileurope claims such a service, but it doesn't seem to be available for Sicily to Milano, and also doesn't seem to cover the idea that, for a given date, some trains are loaded but others are not.

It would be nice to not have to check the Trenitalia website three times a day; and if such a service exists, automated booking systems might well snatch up tickets so quickly that even that is not enough…

Comment: This seems to be a problem not unique to travel: check when a certain website has changed and get an alert if it does. You could look into tools such as  [visualping](https://visualping.io/), [changetower](https://changetower.com/), [huginn](https://github.com/huginn/huginn) or [web alert](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.webalert) but all those only work if there is an URL they can monitor. I am not making this an answer as I don't know if there is a suitable URL, so I can't test my suggestions.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I've used followthatpage myself for job openings in the past, but I don't think any of those services work for dynamic pages. As train booking systems are not _only_ accessible over the web, there might be companies that have privileged access and can automate such checks via other interfaces.

Comment: I'm not sure how much effort you are willing to spend on this and if you are comfortable with scripting, but it appears you can retrieve the website response for a certain origin, destination and date as a [neat json](https://pastebin.com/851VMeqi). [This curl command](https://pastebin.com/RJ3whiN0) does that for a journey query from Fiumefreddo Sicilia to Milano Centralo for 24-11-2023. I unfortunately don't have the time and know-how to setup a monitor to frequently monitor the output of that HTTP call and send an alert if a certain train is in the output, but it seems possible.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Cool!  Just as I was testing your script, they loaded the trains I was looking for :D

Comment: If such a service _did_ exist (assuming it currently does not), then I suspect you would probably find it even harder to book... you'd be fighting everybody who'd registered with such a service, instead of just the people who can be bothered to check for updates frequently.

Comment: @TripeHound Maybe such a service _does_ exist, because by the time I found that tickets were available, around 14 hours after the last time I checkend and they weren't yet, the train was almost fully booked; we were unable to book the private sleeper compartment we wanted, and ended up with two bunks that aren't even in the same coach :-/